# android determine GC freed object

Tags: android, garbage-collection

my android application performance is low. from logcat i found that the time consuming factor is garbage collection. it consumes atleast 110ms in every gc. gc is showing frequently. Is there anyway to determine the collected objects??

Comment: Is this in the emulator or on a real phone?

Comment: Hope you are not using the runtime class to free gc manually anywhere

Comment: @khalos it is Real phone

Comment: How are you seeing the fact that GC takes 110ms?

Comment: from my logcat i saw this type of lines frequently               11-03 11:39:33.830: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14614): GC freed 18683 objects / 590096 bytes in 110ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the videos in the http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html

Especially the one talking on "Make your UI faster", there are a lot of design best practices shown in the videos.

It will definitely help your application to run faster.

Comment: In my application, i have to parse xml file downloaded from server. for parsing the data from each tag i used the method showing below                                                         public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
  
   if(in_mapData){
  if(this.in_evtUrl){ myXmlDataSet.setExtractedEvtUrl(new String(ch, start,length));                  }   this method is called for each tag content reading. Is this the reason forgarbage collection since i use new String() method frequently?? if yes give me a subtitute to this method..

Comment: You will have to trace your methods to check which is generating garbage. Its really difficult to find that with code alone. You can try and use a different parsing implementation.

Comment: i used a class that extends DefaultHandler for handling xml handling. while reading the xml data i am getting the char array. For getting the string i have to convert it to string by calling new String() method. I think this is the reason for GC.If i get the data as string can i solve this problem??? then which is the xml parsing class for getting data as string. I am using HTC wildfire with android version 2.1.

Comment: check this question for a better discussion on XML parsers for android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android

Answer (score 2):

In the DDMS tool, go to the "Allocation Tracker" tab.  Select your app from the list, and click "Start Tracking".  After using the app for a bit, select "Get Allocations".

This will show you the list of the 512 most recent allocations, with sizes and stack traces.  From this you should be able to tell what is eating up memory and causing the GCs.

Comment: In my application, for each touch action, calling new inner class that extends asyncTask. Should i need to construct new class on every touch action?? if i create the inner class as static and call that class instead of calling "new class.execute(parameter)" can i improve performance??

Comment: I don't know.  You may want to open a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an odd value for Android GC. The ~100ms and ~500K values are fairly average but that depends on the project specs of course.The real problem is in the frequency that your code causes the GC to be called.

Here's an example: If you implement lists via the `ListView` and some custom `Adapters` you could get the worst ever performance and the best ever depending on how you write your code for them. If you do not optimize lists and create a new View (by inflating it from the `.xml` file) you will get GC calls very often and this is perceived as small hickups or hangups in the UI.

The best method for determining of what causes the GC problem is localizing it. Start your app and use it one part an a time while monitoring the DDMS for GC gumps and then see which element or Activity causes most of them and go from there.

Also try memory usage monitoring with some tools. For instance if you are using Eclipse there is a tool called [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) that will give you a bit more insight into object usage throughout your project.